# taskKillGracePeriodSeconds is not working for DC/OS Marathon Application?

Tags: marathon, dcos

We have setup DC/OS(version 1.9) Cluster on AWS nodes. We are creating Marathon Application definition with setting **"taskKillGracePeriodSeconds"=60**. We are also catching SIGTERM in our application to handle the application shutdown gracefully. But this is is not wroking, Marathon is immediately killing the Application (on Scale Down / Destroy) and not waits for 60 secs as expected. We are getting callback on SIGTERM but application killed immediately after that. We have also tried with starting Mesos slave agents with setting following attributes in file /var/lib/dcos/mesos-slave-common  **MESOS_ATTRIBUTES=executor_shutdown_grace_period:60secs;docker_stop_timeout:60s
ecs** but this is also not helping.

DCOS Cluster Agents uses **centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64** OS.

Does anybody able to use **taskKillGracePeriodSeconds** successfully.?

Please help to work out this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using Docker containers?

There was a problem as far as I remember when using process groups (=containers) with the forwarding of the SIGTERM signal.

Just to test this on your cluster, can you deploy an app with the following command, just using mesos containerizer and a taskKillGracePeriodSeconds of 10 seconds?

trap "echo ' killing' && sleep 5 && echo 'test' && sleep 100" SIGTERM && sleep 100000

Comment: Yes, we are using Docker Containers.

We are running Java application inside Docker container and we are able to catch the Termination Signal. We have added Runtime.addShutdownHook hook in our application and we are getting callback here when application is killed.But after this application terminated immediately as Marathon stops Docker container.

We have also tried the simple Marathon application which uses mesos containerizer. taskKillGracePeriodSeconds  timeout is working for it.

Is there any way to handle the graceful shutdown of Marathon application runs Docker Container..?

Comment: The problem with docker is, that it depends how you use it. The best way to make sure, that the sigterm is send to the underlying process is, that you use the `entrypoint` functionality within your Dockerfile and don`t use marathon `cmd` section therefore.
If changing to entrypoint does not help in your case, you can post your (stripped down) Dockerfile and your (stripped down) marathon app definition and I will try to reproduce it :)

Comment: With adding entrypoint for container, we are able to catch SIGTERM in java process which we are running in container and also able to handle shutdown of process gracefully. We are also able to use  taskKillGracePeriodSeconds for the same. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is great news!
It would be awesome if you could mark this answer as solving your problem <3